# PHP SOAP Call METHOD with argument

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I am creating a client to access a webservice; the webservice is working correctly.
I need to access a method to get inventory data

```
 http://176.44:8080/wsLogo/wsLogo.asmx
```

I'm using the getITEMS method like this:

```
 http://176.44:8080/wsLogo/wsLogo.asmx?op=getITEMS
```

`code` is blank, `date` is 2013-04-10

I use this code to call that like this

```
ini_set( "soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", 0 );

$client = new SoapClient("http://14:8080/wsLogo/wsLogo.asmx?WSDL");

$ourParamsArray=array('','2013-04-10');

$response=$client->__soapCall('getITEMS', array('parameters' => $ourParamsArray));

print_r($response);
```

but I am not getting the correct results: can anyone help me please?

[Here][1] you can see the current output

```
  [1]: http://onc/jumi/temst.php
```

Answer (score 0):

$yourParamsArray is undefined? You seem to declare it as $ourParamsArray...

Comment: That probably means that the request you are sending is not understood by the server. What is the error message you get? If you see an 'Internal Server Error' (i.e. code 500), try looking in your error log

Comment: but i can call other methods which not request arguments sucesfuly

Comment: i chnage array to $ourParamsArray=array('ITEM'=>'','DATE'=>'2013-04-10'); now its working, can i know how to get those values please

Comment: Those are described in the WSDL. When you read your WSDL, you can see exactly what values (as input) are expected.

Comment: check the var_dump here http://oncorecables.com/stock/jumi/test.php i need to get indevidual values, thank you

Comment: seems it getting a xml file

Answer (score 0):

I chnage array to

```
$ourParamsArray=array('ITEM'=>'','DATE'=>'2013-04-10');
```

the web service identify the name of param.